# Safety of static_cast to pointer-to-derived class from base destructor

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer, static-cast

This is a variant of the questions [Downcasting using the Static_cast in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322949/downcasting-using-the-static-cast-in-c) and [Safety of invalid downcast using static_cast (or reinterpret_cast) for inheritance without added members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372117/safety-of-invalid-downcast-using-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-for-inheritan?rq=1)

I am not clear on the phrase in the standard "B that is actually a subobject of an object of type D, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type D" with respect to behavior in ~B. If you cast to D in ~B, is it still a subobject at that point ?
The following simple example shows the question:

```
void f(B* b);

class B {
public:
  B() {}
  ~B() { f(this); }
};

class D : public B { public: D() {} };

std::set<D*> ds;

void f(B* b) {
  D* d = static_cast<D*>(b);  // UB or subobject of type D?
  ds.erase(d);
}
```

I know that the cast is an open door to disaster, and doing anything like this from the dtor is a bad idea, but a co-worker claims "The code is valid and works correctly. That cast is perfectly valid. The comment clearly states that it should not be dereferenced".

I pointed out that the cast is unnecessary and we should prefer the protection provided by the type system to comments. The sad part is that he is one of the senior/lead developers and a supposed c++ "expert".

Can I tell him the cast is UB ?

Comment: I _think_ this is UB, but I'm not sure. However, the code [at least in this sample] absolute reeks worse than my socks after two-weeks in a hot summer without washing... The correct thing here would be to have a desctructor in `D` that removed the object from `ds` - it should not be done in `B`. This would of course also avoid any problem with UB. The fact that it may indeed work and be well defined is beside the point. Or make `ds` into a `std::set<B*> bs`...

Comment: As long as there do not exist any other classes derived from B and D has no additional members, this might work alright. But the whole thing smells. How can you make sure that every B is a D and if this is sure why would you have different classes in the first place?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Why do you think this is UB? The standard at 5.2.9 gives an example almost equal to the OP's, although it uses references: `struct B { }; struct D : public B { }; D d; B &br = d; static_cast<D&>(br);` Of course, this is just a theoretical question. The code in the OP's question is horrible.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The point is that the conversion in the code in the OP happens *during destruction*, and indeed after `D`'s destructor body has finished execution.

Comment: @T.C.: Ah, I see. You're right, this complicates everything even more. Nice senior developer the OP has there... :)

Comment: [basic.life]/p1 says that an object's lifetime ends as soon as the destructor call starts, and [class.dtor]/p15 says "Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists", which arguably implies that the `D` object "no longer exists" at the time of the `static_cast`. But this is pretty murky.

Comment: FWIW, if we give `B` a virtual function (i.e., making it polymorphic), clang's UB sanitizer will error on this code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df0100a0248695a4

Comment: This code is idiotic. Why would anyone think this to be a good idea??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[expr.static.cast]/p11:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `B`,” where B is a class type, can
>   be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv2* `D`,” where `D` is a
>   class derived (Clause 10) from `B`, if a valid standard conversion
>   from “pointer to `D`” to “pointer to `B`” exists (4.10), *cv2* is the
>   same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*, and
>   `B` is neither a virtual base class of `D` nor a base class of a
>   virtual base class of `D`. The null pointer value (4.10) is converted
>   to the null pointer value of the destination type. If the prvalue of
>   type “pointer to *cv1* `B`” points to a `B` that is actually a subobject
>   of an object of type `D`, the resulting pointer points to the
>   enclosing object of type `D`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The question, then, is whether, at the time of the `static_cast`, the pointer actually points to "a `B` that is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`". If so, there is no UB; if not, then the behavior is undefined **whether or not the resulting pointer is dereferenced or otherwise used**.

[class.dtor]/p15 says that (emphasis mine)

> Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object **no longer
>   exists**

and [basic.life]/p1 says that

> The lifetime of an object of type `T` ends when:
>
> - if T is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (12.4), the destructor call starts, or
> - [...]

From this, then, the `D` object's lifetime has ended as soon as its destructor is invoked, and certainly by the time `B`'s destructor began to execute - which is after `D`'s destructor body has finished execution. At this point, there is no "object of type `D`" left that this `B` can be a subobject of - it "no longer exists". Thus, you have UB.

Clang with UBsan will [report an error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df0100a0248695a4) on this code if `B` is made polymorphic (given a virtual function), which supports this reading.

Comment: "if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists"  - please refer to 12.7/3: which explains that this pointer conversion  is valid as long as  "destruction of these classes shall not have **completed**" and UB otherwhise.  As here desturction of D is completed and the one of B has started, it's definitively UB !

Comment: @Christophe “pointer to D” and “pointer to B” are types, and that sentence is dealing with types, not values. A "valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists" as long as B is an accessible and unambiguous base of `D` (see [conv.ptr]/p3).

Comment: For my own understanding: If the object does no more exist after the destructor has startet, why am I allowed to call any clean-up function within it?

Comment: @KitFisto There's a paragraph in the standard ([class.cdtor]/p4) that explicitly allows member function calls during construction or destruction.

Comment: Thanks, T.C. that is what I was thinking too. I was hoping to find a clear & compelling definition of "subobject" relevant to this context since that seems to be the key term as you point out.

Comment: @T.C: Thanks, that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your co-worker is under the impression that as long as you do not dereference an invalid pointer, you are fine.

He is **wrong**.

Merely evaluating such a pointer has undefined behaviour. This code is obviously broken.

Comment: It's implementation-defined, not undefined, but the implementation-defined behaviour has a footnote attached that says "Some implementations might define that copying an invalid pointer value causes a system-generated runtime fault." However, the pointer doesn't become invalid until after the deallocation function runs. Pointers to uninitialised storage remain valid pointers, and the storage remains available until the deallocation function runs. I think T.C.'s answer gives a more convincing argument that the code nonetheless has UB.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitively tell him that it's UB !  !

**Why ?**

> **12.4/7:** Bases and members are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of their constructor The objects are detroyed in the
>   reverse order of their constuction.
>
> **12.6.2/10:** First (...) virtual base classes are initialized (...) then, direct base classes are initialized

So when destructing a D, first the D members are destructed and then the D sub object, and only then will B be destructed.

This code makes sure that `f()` is called when the B object is destroyed:

```
 ~B() { f(this); }
```

So when a D object is destroyed,  the D suboject is destroyed first, and then ~B() is executed, calling `f()`.

In `f()` you cast the pointer to a B as pointer to a D. **This is UB:**

> **3.8/5:** (...) after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any
>   pointer that refers to the storage location where the object will be
>   or was located
>   **may be used but only in limited ways**.
>   (...) The program has **undefined behavior** if the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the
>   object, or (...) **the pointer is used as the operand of a static_cast**.

Comment: "static casting a pointer will not touch the object itself. So this statement alone is not UB in the sence that nothing undefined will happen immediately." No, a `static_cast` can itself be UB.

Comment: Indeed, a `static_cast` on something that is not really of that type  is UB. `reinterpret_cast` would be OK, as long as it's not dereferenced.

Comment: @T.C. Ooops !  You're completely right !  I thought that only the derefencing of suc a casted poitner was UB, but following your remark, I've found a quote of the standard that explicitely addresses the static_casting after end of life of object.  I edited the post: no longer any doubt: that's UB ! Thanks for the hint !

Comment: I'm doubtful about the 3.8/5 quote because that paragraph explicitly excludes "an object under construction or destruction".

Comment: @JonathanWakely in fact T.C. was right:  the static_cast is UB except if the cast is to `void*`, `char*` or `unsigned char*`

Comment: @T.C: It's not clear how much of the rest of the paragraph is discounted by trhat

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, you are certainly allowed to access your own non-static data members in a destructor body, even though the object's lifetime has ended by then.

Comment: @Christophe, yes, I know, that's why I agreed with T.C. (and upvoted the comment)

Comment: @T.C. I agree with *Lightness Races in Orbit* :  for the exlusion refers to 12.7 which addresses some special cases, but doesn't invalidate what I quoted. The last sentence of 12.7/3 tend even to reinforces it : the simple fact forming a pointer to a member after the object was destroyed is already UB.

Comment: @T.C.: "In the destructor body" and "after destruction" are two completely different things. Though yes I acknowledge that the object's lifetime has already ended in both cases.

Comment: @Christophe I disagree; "For X, see Y; otherwise Z" implies that Z doesn't apply in X. Remember that in the body of `~D()`, `D`'s lifetime has already ended. `~D() { delete this->D::ptr;}` is obviously valid, which implies that the bullets in 3.8/5 cannot possibly apply to the "object under construction and destruction" case; instead the rules in 12.7 apply.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I honestly like that argument, but annoyingly `D`'s destructor doesn't technically finish execution until all the members and bases have been destroyed. Their destructors are specified to be called by the destructor of `D` ([class.dtor]/p8), so until those calls finishes `D`'s destructor is still executing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There's no "direct non-static member" here...?

Comment: @T.C. Whoops ;) Right well then there are no semantics defined for this so it's UB.